# Why getting ip address in php gives different ip's (IE vs Firefox)?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox

I use the command:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

to get the ip address.

IE gives me the ip address of my machine and Firefox gives me the Default Gateway.

Why is this happening?
How can I get the ip address when using a proxy?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you 100% sure IE is actually *using* the proxy?

Comment: Occam's razor says that the proxy isn't working in IE.

Comment: Ups, actually both are not using it oO the ip that I gave is on the "do not use proxy" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both browsers from the same source machine to the same destination are giving different IP addresses then either:

1. One of the browsers is accessing the destination via a proxy and the other isn't
2. One (or both) browsers are spoofing their IP address

As it's you running the browsers I think it's safe to assume you're not spoofing the IP address.  This must mean that one browser is using a proxy and the other isn't.  Double check your browser settings regarding proxies.

As an aside, this should also be an important lesson regarding the REMOTE_ADDR field in particular and user-supplied input in general.  namely, you can't trust it to be accurate.

Comment: the problem is that "do not use proxy" in firefox doesn't work unless I put the full ip address. In IE I put something like 10.* and it works for all 10..... sites